# How can I create VBA code that when using check box an item appears when unchecked goes away?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to set up a Form check box that if checked a triangle will appear on an image and when unchecked the triangle will go away. I've got the macro to insert the triangle but when I un-check the box it's still there. How can I create this action that when checked appears when unchecked goes away?

Using VBA I've tried to understand how to identify the triangle but how can I have it remove the triangle?

```
Sub InsertTriangle()
'
' InsertTriangle Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeIsoscelesTriangle, 161.25, 210.75, 114.75, _
        171).Select
End Sub
```

When I click on the checkbox a triangle will appear. When I un-check the box the triangle will disappear.

Comment: You'll need to loop through the shapes to find the one that is your specific isosceles triangle and delete it.  Additionally, you could name your shape when you add it, then you just have to delete the named shape.

Answer (score 0):

Building on my comment, specifically the sentence about naming your shape when you add it, like:

```
dim sh as object
set sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeIsoscelesTriangle, 161.25, 210.75, 114.75, 171)
sh.name = "NAME"
```

You can then delete the shape when the box is unchecked, similar to:

```
dim i as shape
for each i in activesheet.shapes
    if i.name = "NAME" then sh.Delete
    exit for
next i
```